# Adding a keylistener to main() not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

I'm making a game in Java where a ball moves forward constantly with no user control, but the user can control the vertical movement of the ball, using the up and down arrow keys, however I'm stuck on adding the keylistener class/whatever it is to my JFrame, through my main method. Basically, I do `add(keylistener_class/method)`, and Java (quite rightly), complains that my class or method is not a component. My question, then, is how AM I supposed to add the keylistener into my Jframe?

Cheers,
Matt

Code:

```
    package org.ultraluminous.vertiball;
```

`import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel{
    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;
    static int ys = 0;

private static void shift(){
    x+=1;
    y+=ys;
    }

public static void event(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        ys = 1;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        ys = -1;
    }
}

public class key{
public void Listen() {
    KeyListener listener = new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    };
    addKeyListener(listener);
    setFocusable(true);
}
}   
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D Graph = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Graph.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Graph.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        Graph.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame Win = new JFrame("Pong");
            Game game = new Game();
            Win.add(new Game());
            //Win.add... add what? I need to add the key listener here    
            //but seem to be unable to.
            Win.setResizable(false);
            Win.setSize(900, 600);
            Win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Win.setVisible(true);
            while (true) {
                shift();
                Win.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding the KeyListener to your `JFrame`. Alternatively you could create a separate class for the KeyListener and add it that way (instead of using an anonymous inner class). Here is what I added:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame Win = new JFrame("Pong");
            Game game = new Game();
            Win.add(new Game());
            Win.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                        ys = -1;
                    }
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                        ys = 1;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                }

            });
            Win.setResizable(false);
            Win.setSize(900, 600);
            Win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Win.setVisible(true);
            while (true) {
                shift();
                Win.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add KeyListener to your JPanel by this way:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

    ...//all the methods.

});
```

Alternatively, you can use `KeyAdpater`, if do not use all the methods.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

    ...//Only the methods you want.

});
```